# How to select multiple cells from a Workbook and paste in another?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select specific cells from one Workbook and paste them in a specific order in another Workbook. Please excuse me as this is my first time coding in excel. This will probably look very trivial.

```
Workbooks("201103 COST BREAKDOWN  March 2011.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("D4,D8").Copy _
  Workbooks("Classification Cost.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4,D8") 
Workbooks("Classification Cost.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G5,G11").Value = _ 
  Workbooks("201103 COST BREAKDOWN  March 2011.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("D4,D8").Value
```

I get

> "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `.Copy` when multi-select *non adjacent* cells like `"D4,D8"` you need to do a copy action for D4 and then another for D8.

But if you only want to copy the values (no formattings) then you can do:

```
Workbooks("Classification Cost.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4,D8").Value = _
  Workbooks("201103 COST BREAKDOWN  March 2011.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("D4,D8").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

1. for the first cline (Copy) remove the `.Value` in the target. A range is expected
2. I don't think you can paste to a discontinuous range. You will then have to have 1 line  for each cell in this case.
3. Same applies for your second construct `Range1.value = Range2.Value`: no discontinuous range, so you'll have to make it 2 lines